# No Carrier error when creating tap Interface for KVM Bridge

Tags: kvm, bridge, iproute

[image: Interfaces]

I have tried to create tap interface (**tap210i0**) manually for kvm. But each time the Tun device shows **NO-CARRIER**.

I have interfaces **eno1**, **eno2**, **vmbr0** and **tap210i0**. eno1 and eno2 are **slaves** for **vmbr0**.

Here are a set of command that I have tried.

```
ip tuntap add tap210i0 mode tap

ip link set dev tap210i0 up

ip link set tap210i0 master vmbr0
```

When I type ***"brctl show"*** it shows ***"tap210i0"*** as one of the interface together with eno1. I have google around but did not found any direct answer for my problem.

I believe I also have tap modules working.

```
lsmod | egrep -si tap
```

*output :*

> tap         24576    1 vhost_net

Note that all kind of firewall are disable. (including iptables)

Can anyone give me any working suggestion ? Please do not suggest me to restart the network as I can only access this server remotely. I could not go to the physical server to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [TAP](https://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/) interface provides a virtual link with two sides:

- the *interface* side seen by the network layer on the host, which for OP's use case is often in tap mode (layer 2 Ethernet) and set as a bridge port.
- an *invisible* side: a *process* having opened a file descriptor to a special device (`/dev/net/tun`), which allows this process to read and write IP packets (tun mode) or Ethernet frames (tap mode). Those packets either come from or go to the interface side of the host.

Creating the interface isn't the most important part. The most important part is having a process attached to the invisible side of this interface to read and write packets. As long as there's no such process, the communication over this link doesn't exist. This is naturally translated as "NO-CARRIER" because it makes sense. This is a normal and expected behaviour.

Three examples of such processes that come to me are QEMU (which provides the device emulation to KVM, including network interfaces), OpenVPN and openssh's Tunnel option.

Normally you would let *qemu* or an helper to *qemu*, or *libvirtd* create itself the interface (and while at it attach it to the bridge) and hand *qemu* what's needed to have the corresponding file descriptor in use. The interface would then have this invisible other side handling it correctly: *qemu*, and it would report a carrier is detected. It might be possible to hand the manually created interface to *qemu* (or *libvirtd* etc.) yourself, but as it's not the usual method, you'll have extra work to do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually I'm using Proxmox. But the Tap interface gone. I don't have the privilege to reinstall the network or reinstall Proxmox itself. I can only fix it remotely. However when I tried to run KVM manually, it produce error :

`network script /var/lib/qemu-server/pve-bridge failed with status 256`

Comment: I guess this is the helper: it has the privileges to create the interface and open the file descriptor (which qemu itself might not have). Then it will hand this file descriptor to qemu. Alas I can't know what means "status 256". You might have changed its configuration and get it to complain.